# Using smart pointers with MySQL Connector

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, mysql-connector

Most tutorials related to the mysql connector libraries assume, that the user will use raw pointers. I'd like to use smart pointers instead. I've written the following class:

```
class Database{
    private:
        bool _connected = false;
        std::shared_ptr<sql::Driver> _driver;
        std::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> _connection;
        std::shared_ptr<sql::Statement> _statement;
        std::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> _resource;
    public:
        Database();
        ~Database();
        bool connect(const std::string &ip, const std::string &user, const std::string password);
        bool connected();
};
```

I'm trying to implement the `connect` function, but I receive the following error during compilation:

```
/usr/include/c++/5.3.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘sql::Driver’
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

It is caused by the following line of code:

```
this->_driver = std::make_shared<sql::Driver>(get_driver_instance());
```

What am I doing wrong? I've found few examples with smart pointers, but in every single one of them the `sql::Driver` instance is a raw pointer. Is it impossible to assign a result of the `get_driver_instance()` function to a smart pointer?

**Update**:

I think I should use the `reset` function instead of the `make_shared` template. Unfortunately this:

```
this->_driver.reset(get_driver_instance());
```

didn't solve the problem, I got this error:

```
/usr/include/cppconn/driver.h:39:10: error: ‘virtual sql::Driver::~Driver()’ is protected
virtual ~Driver() {}
```

I guess that the `shared_ptr` is unable to "claim" the Driver's destructor, because it's protected (as said in the error). Is there any workaround? Or maybe I should simply use a raw pointer when dealing with the `sql::Driver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting driver object pointer from `get_driver_instance()` is pointer to static storage object AFAIK and that pointer may not be `delete`d. So you do not need a smart pointer for managing its life time. Static objects are destroyed when program ends. Other objects in your post (`sql::Connection`, `sql::Statement`, `sql::ResultSet`) need to be deleted
so you can use smart pointer for managing those.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice that indeed no one is deleting the driver pointer in their examples.